# Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint - MySQL (Simple Tables)

Tags: mysql, database

The current tables I have are as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE course(
       CourseNum INT(11),
       CourseName VARCHAR(30),
       NumOfUnit INT(11),
       PRIMARY KEY(CourseNum)
    );

    CREATE TABLE timeandloc(
       CourseNum INT(11),
       Quarter VARCHAR(20),
       DayTime VARCHAR(40),
       RoomNum INT,
       PRIMARY KEY(CourseNum, Quarter, DayTime),
       FOREIGN KEY(CourseNum) REFERENCES course (CourseNum)
    );
```

I was able to add those fine using a query, but when I try to add this table:

```
    CREATE TABLE student(
       StudentName VARCHAR(30),
       CourseNum INT(11),
       Quarter VARCHAR(20),
       PRIMARY KEY(StudentName, CourseNum, Quarter),
       FOREIGN KEY(CourseNum) REFERENCES course(CourseNum),
       FOREIGN KEY(Quarter) REFERENCES timeandloc(Quarter)
    );
```

I get

> Error code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint.

It seems to be this line that's the culprit:

```
    FOREIGN KEY(Quarter) REFERENCES timeandloc(Quarter)
```

When I try to add the table without that line, everything works fine without a hitch.

I'm very new to MySQL and databases in general so I'm not sure what's wrong. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a separate index on Quarter field in timeandloc table and then create problematic create table query.

```
alter table timeandloc add index idx_Quarter(Quarter);

CREATE TABLE student(
       StudentName VARCHAR(30),
       CourseNum INT(11),
       Quarter VARCHAR(20),
       PRIMARY KEY(StudentName, CourseNum, Quarter),
       FOREIGN KEY(CourseNum) REFERENCES course(CourseNum),
       FOREIGN KEY(Quarter) REFERENCES timeandloc(Quarter)
    );
```

**Update:**

For performance point of view joining field in both tables (parent/child) should be indexed. When we create foreign key then mysql itself create an index on the field we create foreign key but could not allow without index on referenced column in referenced table. As index works from left to right, so in your case index for Quarter column will not be used from primary key, so need to create a separate index on it.

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to have worked for me, but I don't seem to understand why. Would you mind explaining as to _why_ this worked for me?

Comment: Please check reason in post.